# windows identity foundation / update panel / error 401

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, wif

i recently created a claim aware web app using wif. 
This app contains an update panel that loads dynamically user controls, everything seems to be ok, but sometimes i am getting a 401 error when the app does a async requet for the updatepanel , but the fedauth cookie is still there and with valid lifetime, also the sts session cookie. 
I tried to implement sliding sessions but the error seems to be still there
wandering if someone could shed some light here.

Btw, my web.config on the client app, looks like this

```html
<federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" issuer="https://stsissuerurl" realm="http://webapp.com" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" persistentSessionLifetime="05:00:00" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled WIF tracing and seen if any clues there? [WIF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517282.aspx)